ADSI - Getting lastLogon property for computer from Active Directory?
How can I retrieve the lastLogon attribute for the computers via Active Directory?  If I go to the server and open a computer in the Active Directory snap-in, I can see it under the Attribute Editor tab.
Below is the test  program, I tried pADs->GetInfo() before trying to get it as well, it didn't help, but also cause a huge delay as it attempted to connect with all the computers that no longer exist or turned off.
#include <windows.h>
#include <activeds.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Activeds.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "ADSIid.Lib")

int main() {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize COM library." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    IADsContainer* pContainer = NULL;
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"WinNT://mydomain", NULL, NULL, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, IID_IADsContainer, (void**)&pContainer);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind to Active Directory." << std::endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IEnumVARIANT* pEnum = NULL;
    hr = ADsBuildEnumerator(pContainer, &pEnum);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to get enumerator." << std::endl;
        pContainer->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    VARIANT var;
    ULONG lFetch;
    IDispatch* pDispatch = NULL;
    IADs* pADs = NULL;
    BSTR bstrClass;

    while (S_OK == ADsEnumerateNext(pEnum, 1, &var, &lFetch)) {
        pDispatch = V_DISPATCH(&var);
        hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IADs, (void**)&pADs);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = pADs->get_Class(&bstrClass);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                if (_wcsicmp(bstrClass, L"computer") == 0) {
                    CComVariant vardate;
                    hr = pADs->Get(CComBSTR(L"lastLogon"), &vardate);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                       // *********** NEVER GET HERE **************
                    }

                    BSTR bstrName;
                    hr = pADs->get_Name(&bstrName);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                        std::wcout << L"Computer: " << bstrName << std::endl;
                        SysFreeString(bstrName);
                    }
                }
                SysFreeString(bstrClass);
            }
            pADs->Release();
        }
        VariantClear(&var);
    }

    ADsFreeEnumerator(pEnum);
    pContainer->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}


lastLogon attribute for a user/computer is updated only on the domain controller that validated the logon, this attribute is NOT synced to any other domain controller in the same domain.
LastLogonTimeStamp is the replicated version that may be used. This attribute is replicated to other DCs in the same domain.
Lastlogon attribute is more up-to-date, but the application has to look for every DC since it is not replicated. This might cause significant delay.
The disadvantage of using LastLogonTimeStamp is this field may be update x days later where x is related to another attribute called ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval with a default value of 14 days.
Ref: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/8220-the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-8221-8211-8220-what-it-was/ba-p/396204
